# sendgrid unit test with typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, sendgrid

I am trying to perform a unit test of this service with sendGrid but I have not been able to do it, I have been trying another question I saw here but it has not helped me yet, I have not been able to test this service, I would appreciate any guidance to do this.

[Test Sendgrid implementation with Jest and Mock in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59108624/test-sendgrid-implementation-with-jest-and-mock-in-node-js)

[image: coverage]

sendgrid.provider.ts

```
export const sendgridProvider = [
  {
    provide: 'SENDGRID_PROVIDER',
    inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: async (
      configService: ConfigService,
    ): Promise<typeof SendGrid> => {
      const { apiKey } = configService.get('sendgrid');
      SendGrid.setApiKey(apiKey);
      return SendGrid;
    },
  },
];
```

sendgrind.services.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SendGridService {
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  constructor(
    @Inject('SENDGRID_PROVIDER') private sendGrid,
    private configService: ConfigService,
    private firestoreService: FirestoreService,
    private logger: Logger,
  ) {
    console.log('aqui estoy', this.sendGrid);
  }

  async sendEmail(sendEmail: SendEmailDto, tenantId: string): Promise<any> {
    const { email, subject, text } = sendEmail;
    const emailFrom = this.configService.get<string>('sendgrid.email');
    const msg = {
      to: email, // Change to your recipient
      from: emailFrom, // Change to your verified sender
      subject,
      text,
    };
    return this.sendGrid
      .send(msg)
      .then(async (response: any) => {
        await this.firestoreService.save(`${tenantId}_emails`, uuidv4(), {
          ...sendEmail,
        });
        this.logger.log({
          message: 'email send',
          payload: response,
        });
        return 'success';
      })
      .catch(async (error: any) => {
        await this.firestoreService.save(`${tenantId}_emails`, uuidv4(), {
          ...sendEmail,
          error: { ...error.response.body },
        });
        this.logger.error({
          message: 'an error occurred while sending the email',
          payload: error,
        });
        throw new Error(error);
      });
  }
}
```

sendgrind.services.spec.ts

```
describe('#sendEmail', () => {
  let sendGridService: SendGridService;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: SendGridService,
          useValue: {
            sendEmail: () => 'success',
          },
        },
        {
          provide: FirestoreService,
          useValue: {
            save: () => true,
          },
        },
        {
          provide: 'SENDGRID_PROVIDER',
          useValue: {
            send: () => jest.fn(),
          },
        },
      ],
      //imports: [FilesModule],
    })
      .setLogger(new Logger())
      .compile();

    sendGridService = module.get<SendGridService>(SendGridService);
  });

  const mockEmail = {
    email: 'receiver@mail.com',
    subject: 'TEST Sendgrid with SendGrid is Fun',
    text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  };

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('Should send mail with specefic value', async () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const mResponse = 'success';
    const result = ['test'];
    //mockedSendGrid.send.mockResolvedValueOnce({ statusCode: 201 });
    expect(await sendGridService.sendEmail(mockEmail, 'someid')).toBe(
      'success',
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Rather than use `SendGrid` directly in the `SendGridService`, why not create a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) and inject the `SendGrid` value, so that you can mock it easily later

Comment: @JayMcDoniel thank you very much for your help, I have updated and created a provider for that, I have updated the question with all the changes and I have left an image with the coverage, I have another question, how could I test there the lines that are not covered?